# Next.js no longer pre-generates page HTML

Tags: javascript, reactjs, next.js, shopify-api

I'm building a Jamstack application with Next.js and at some point over the past month or so, the pages stopped pre-generating the HTML (the pages hydrate just fine on load, so I didn't notice when this happened).

Using the world's simplest component in the `pages` directory:

```js
const Test = () => {
  return <h1>Hello worm</h1>;
};

export default Test;
```

... results in an empty `<div id="__next"></div>` element in the markup sent to the browser (the same is true when I use `props`, `getStaticPaths()` or `getStaticProps()`).

I'm aware that some Redux packages can cause this behaviour, but I'm not using Redux. My `package.json` looks like this:

```js
{
  "name": "sprintwell-takeshape",
  "version": "0.1.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "dev": "next dev",
    "build": "next build",
    "start": "next start"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "@takeshape/routing": "^7.38.2",
    "isomorphic-fetch": "^3.0.0",
    "next": "^10.2.3",
    "next-pwa": "^5.2.23",
    "react": "17.0.2",
    "react-dom": "17.0.2",
    "react-markdown": "^6.0.2",
    "sass": "^1.34.1",
    "shopify-buy": "^2.11.0"
  }
}
```

(Edit)
Just to add to the confusion, when I do a build, the results page implies that the pages built *do* have pre-generated HTML:

```
Page                                                           Size     First Load JS
┌ ● /                                                          732 B           149 kB
├   /_app                                                      0 B            83.3 kB
├ ● /[slug]                                                    910 B           149 kB
├   ├ /guarantee
├   ├ /privacy-policy
├   ├ /terms
├   └ [+7 more paths]
├ ○ /404                                                       3.74 kB        87.1 kB
├ λ /api/add-email                                             0 B            83.3 kB
├ ● /collections (ISR: 86400 Seconds)                          1.59 kB         149 kB
├ ● /collections/[slug]                                        1.91 kB         150 kB
├   ├ /collections/tea-cosies
├   ├ /collections/mp3-players
├   ├ /collections/clothing
├   └ [+5 more paths]
├ ● /products (ISR: 86400 Seconds)                             1.76 kB         150 kB
├ ● /products/[slug]                                           2.07 kB         150 kB
├   ├ /products/checkerboard-tea-cosy
├   ├ /products/fair-isle-cosy
├   ├ /products/christmas-cosy
├   └ [+27 more paths]
└ ● /test (ISR: 86400 Seconds)                                 304 B          83.6 kB
+ First Load JS shared by all                                  83.3 kB
  ├ chunks/0999c87ecb7e0a864f9e303ce1593fb7c2a32c6e.bbad1c.js  13.3 kB
  ├ chunks/11100001.b545b5.js                                  13.6 kB
  ├ chunks/framework.f8bd46.js                                 42.1 kB
  ├ chunks/main.fd1a9a.js                                      9.46 kB
  ├ chunks/pages/_app.3df493.js                                4.08 kB
  ├ chunks/webpack.50bee0.js                                   751 B
  └ css/b93e53639e8085f31884.css                               16.5 kB
```

Can anyone point me in the right direction?

Comment: Maybe you do something weird in your custom app or document?

Comment: Can you share pages/app file and your configs "next.config.js" also !

Comment: Thanks, Danila and Mohammad - I've been going through my Git logs and I suspect you're right.

Answer (score 0):

For future folk, here's what was happening. The logic for my checkout was based on [TakeShape's example Shopify repo](https://github.com/takeshape/takeshape-starter-shopify-nextjs). That puts a lot of logic [in `_app.js`](https://github.com/takeshape/takeshape-starter-shopify-nextjs/blob/main/src/pages/_app.js), including this section around line 81:

```js
let content;
if (shopify === null || checkoutId === null) {
  content = null;
} else {
  content = <Component {...pageProps} />;
```

`content` is used in the `return` of the app component. I included this code without really thinking why it was there. My current guess is that it's to hide errors, if it runs server-side and the objects don't exist. However, it should be noted, this code causes no issues on [the live version of TakeShape's demo](https://shape-shop-next.vercel.app/).

In my version, it doesn't seem to complain when I add `<Component {...pageProps} />` back into the `return` statement. So ... fixed?